# Tabulate JSON into Sheets

Tags: json, google-apps-script, import, google-sheets, custom-function

I've been trying to get a readable database of a JSON file from a URL.

I've used fastfedora's script on Github, https://github.com/fastfedora/google-docs/blob/master/scripts/ImportJSON/Code.gs, to import JSON from the URL to Sheets. I'm using the basic:

```
=TRANSPOSE(ImportJSON("https://rsbuddy.com/exchange/summary.json"))
```

I used transpose as it was easier to work with two long columns rather than two long rows.

The data that's been imported however, is very messy: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mKnRQmshbi1YFG9HHg7-mKlZZzpgDME6-eGjDJKzbRY/edit?usp=sharing. It's basically 1 long column of descriptive data, (name, id, price etc.) and another column of the variable (the actual name of the item and it's price in digits).

Is it possible to manipulate the resultant Sheets page so that the common factors in the first column can be lined up with the pseudo-table beside two initial columns? E.g. for the first item, the ID will be '2', the name will be 'Cannonball', the Sp will be '5' etc.

Thanks in advance. Do forgive me for my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is structured and every object will always have the same structure you can use a simple offset to do this:

```
=OFFSET($B$2,
        (ROW($B2) - 2) * 7 +
         COLUMN(D$1) - 4, 
        0)
```

Put that in D2 and drag to the right and down.
It is possible to immediately return the data in this fashion but for that you need to meddle with the script.

Comment: If your problem has been solved please consider accepting the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 1):

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hv1yRgSOUIZqICkAAQUT9qj8yo7iMqQ6gs-Z9ll1_k0/edit?usp=sharing)

### **Simple formula**

I think, faster way to get **IDs**:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A2:B,"select B where A <> '' offset 4"),"skipping 7")
```

and if you want **Names**:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A2:B,"select B where A <> '' offset 1"),"skipping 7")
```

- when you change offset from 0 to 6, you get different columns
  outputs.
- `7` is the number of columns in Data.

The result is autocompleted column with Data.

---

### **Hard formula**

Also possible to get the whole result with one formula:

1. paste `=COUNTA(A:A)` in cell `E2`
2. paste `7` in `E3`, this is the number of columns in Data
3. `=E2/E3` in `E4`

And then in cell `G2` or somewhere on right paste the formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(if(COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,1,E3)),    
(row(OFFSET(A1,,,E4))-1)*E3+COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,1,E3))),    
{row(OFFSET(A1,,,E2)),OFFSET(B2,,,E2)},2,0))
```

It works slow, but gives the whole table.

---

### **or Script?**

I've also tried to use script UDF function. Here's test formula:

```
=ConvertTo2D(TRANSPOSE(R3:R16),7)
```

where R3:R16 is small range which was splited into table with 7 columns. The script is pretty short:

```
function ConvertTo2D(Arr, index) {

   var newArr = [];
   while(Arr[0].length) newArr.push(Arr[0].splice(0,index));

   return newArr; 

}
```

Sounds good. But! It is ve-e-e-e-ery slow. So This solution is good only for quick test.

Comment: The reason why the script is so slow is due to the splicing, the array has the be rebuilt every time and all the elements moved by one spot. It would be faster to just iterate through it.